# How to add custom fields in sales_shipment_items in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How can I add custom fields in **sales_shipment_item** using upgrade schema in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('sales_shipment_item'),
                'your_custom_field',
                [
                    'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' => 'Custom Field Description'
                ]
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

In cases that you have to add again another **custom field**, you just have to change the **setup_version** of your custom module from **module.xml**.
Assuming you have an upgrade to your custom module,
let's say from **version 1.0.1 to version 1.0.2**, just do like this in your **upgradeSchema:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CutomModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
                $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                    $setup->getTable('sales_shipment_item'),
                    'your_custom_field',
                    [
                        'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'comment' => 'Custom Field Description'
                    ]
                );
            }

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('sales_shipment_item'),
                'your_custom_field2',
                [
                        'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'comment' => 'Custom Field2 Description'
                ]
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: its working perfectly.